# Datatype for membership-testing in multiprocessing environment

Tags: python, shared-objects, python-multithreading

I am working on a web crawler and I am using multiprocessing, to download and process four pages at a time. But of cause I do not intend to crawl the same page more than once.

Before I implemented multiprocessing i used Sets to maintain a collection of cralwled URLs, I choose Sets, because they are ideal for membership-testing. I thougt that multiprocessing.Manager could help me to implement a shared Set between the four processes. But it does not seam to be the case.

What I want to do is something like

```
manager = Manager()
d = manager.set()
```

But no such function exist in the Manager class.

Does anyone have a idea how to solve, or a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either use list as your base store of visited websites.
1) Lock
2) Check if array have value
3) Add url if was not visited
4) Unlock

Or create another process where you will have normal set where you can put your urls.
Any process that need to check if website was visited just talk to that one process via Queue or Pipe.

Answer (score 0):

`multiprocessing` does have an implementation of `dict()`, which should be a functional replacement to `set()` for membership testing.

Simply use the keys to store which urls you want to do membership lookups on, and store whatever you wish in the value:

```
d = manager.dict()

# Store some values
d['http://dr.dk'] = 1
d['http://stackoverflow.com'] = 1

# Do membership lookup
if 'http://stackoverflow.com' in d:
    print "We have visited Stack Overflow"

if 'http://google.com' not in d:
    print "We have not visited Google"
```